# Drupal 8 Url::FromRoute toString() Don't take the braces

Tags: php, url, drupal-8, tostring, braces

I would like to recover a road with `URL::FromRoute`
Except that I have some concerns when I use to `toString`

```
$path = Url::fromRoute('my_route_name',['mypParamsId' =>  'MYPARAMSID'])->toString();
```

In this way I find a road but it's not the right one

I wish I could recover that

```
$path = Url::fromRoute('my_route_name',['mypParamsId' =>  '{MYPARAMSID}'])->toString();
```

But when I use the toString it does not work and Drupal cannot access my route and if I remove the String it returns my object to me without error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$myurl = Url::fromRoute('my_route_name',['mypParamsId' =>  $theValue]);
$link = \Drupal::service(‘link_generator’)->generate(‘title’, $myurl);
```

Then print $myurl
Because, it implements _toString()

Or
Using Drupal\Core\Link for the 2nd line

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('myrouteName', array(
          'My_id' => $item->id
    ));

$link= Link::fromTextAndUrl($item->id, $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_path = Url::fromRoute('<current>', [], ['absolute' => 'true']);
```